# JSON viewer for firebug not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, firebug

in firebug it says the headers are `content type: application/json`, but I only have headers and response tabs (no json tab) my response is valid json: `[{"id":"1","date":"2011-05-21 22:00:00","location":"roppongi","description":"blah","extra":"lbah"}]`
But why can't I use the json viewer in firebug to see it. It bother's me because my json viewer works for other sites (http://www.janodvarko.cz/firebug/tests/1275/Issue1275.htm)
Thank you.. let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Can you show a link that's not working?

Comment: i'll have it on a server in about an hour (working behind a router on localhost atm)

Comment: Check out http://jsonview.com/ I much preffer it to the JSON viewer in Firebug 'cuz it lets you view the data full screen. Just right click the request and 'Open in new tab'. it'll preserve post-data too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, it works for me in Firebug 1.7.2:

[image]

For what it's worth, Firebug doesn't require a proper content-type be set for the JSON viewer to kick in.